# difference between IdLookUp from External Id

Tags: apex, trigger

What is the difference between IdLookUp from External Id?

Answer (score 2):

Per the documentation:

idlookup:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/access_for_fields.htm

> Can be used to specify a record in an upsert call. The Id field of each object has this property and some Name fields. There are exceptions, so check for the property in any object you wish to upset.

basically it is a property of specific field types. Where an external ID is a property you set to indicate a custom field can be used as an external ID. Marking a field as an External ID essentially set the idlookup property to true.

A 10 second search pulled up this information. In the future please be a bit more detailed as to what you do not understand as I am unsure if this it what you were having trouble with. Also, visit Trailhead, lots of fundamental information there.